# Gulp (windows) src file adjusted but gulp using the not updated file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-imports

So this is weird. When a'm at work I am using a mac for development. Sometimes I work from home and at home I use a Windows pc.

At work everyhing is working fine. But today I am working from home and GULP can't run. Even ask my colleagues today to check it and for them everything worked fine.

So the issue. Gulp can't find a file even if it exists.

gulp code:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {

return gulp.src('./js/script.js')
    .pipe(jsImport({hideConsole: true}))
    .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
    // .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../public/js'));
});
```

scripts.js (parial) code:

```
@import "./lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js";
```

(the @import is a gulp exension)

But on my windows it throws this:

```
events.js:174
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: file ./lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js no exist
```

So for the fun of it I removed the import.

Run gulp. And throws same error.

For fun I remove all the code and error still throwing.

It looks like gulp does not use the file with the changes I made to it.

Someone any idea what is going wrong here.

Comment: Do you use same gulp version on both terminals?

Comment: yes I do. I tried another pachage for @import. Its anoher syntax but that worked. So maybe that package does not work for windows...